# Eliminate duplicate records that are in consecutive rows

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

So I have a table full of data that can have some duplicate entries that need to be grouped together, but I'm a little unsure on how to approach doing so.

Here is a sample of the data:

```
+-------+---------------------+------------+--+
| id    | timestamp           | customerID |  |
+-------+---------------------+------------+--+
| 15711 | 2016-05-07 00:46:11 | 11191      |  |
| 15710 | 2016-05-07 00:46:11 | 11191      |  |
| 15709 | 2016-05-07 00:46:05 | 10076      |  |
| 15708 | 2016-05-07 00:46:04 | 10076      |  |
| 15707 | 2016-05-07 00:23:57 | 11192      |  |
| 15706 | 2016-05-07 00:13:59 | 11189      |  |
| 15705 | 2016-05-07 00:05:27 | 11188      |  |
+-------+---------------------+------------+--+
```

If you look at the first two rows (ids 15711 and 15710) they have the exact same timestamp, so you'd think I could just group by timestamp. However if you look at the next two rows (15709 and 15708) you can see that the timestamps differ by a second. In my data these timestamps can differ by a few seconds, but if they are in consecutive rows like that I want to group them together.

They usually come in pairs, but I've seen groups of three as well.

What is the best way of grouping these rows together?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given the data set above, what would the desired result set look like?

Comment: What happens if you have a chain of 100 rows that are all one second apart?  Also, in your data, it looks like aggregating by customer id does what you want.

Comment: I'd like for rows 15711 and 15710 to be grouped together as well as 15709 and 15708. Their exact timestamp or id doesn't matter necessarily. I'm going to be doing a count on this data and want to remove the duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, I do want to aggregate by customerID, except its possible for the same customerID to show up on the same day yet I want to count them separately unless they are in consecutive rows.

Comment: Please edit your question to demonstrate a desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to identify "episodes" for a single customer, you can do this as:

```
select customerId, count(*) as numrows,
       min(id), max(id), min(timestamp), max(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(@c = customerId, @grp,
                         if(@c := customerId, @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                        )
             ) as grp
      from t cross join
           (select @c := '', @grp:= 0) params
      order by id
     ) t
group by customer, grp;
```